# Connection between Möbius and  function

Tags: nt.number-theory

How can we from   $\sum_{n\leqslant x}\mu (n)=o(x)$  deduce $\sum_{n\leqslant x}(-1)^{\omega(n)}=o(x)$, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of different primes dividing $n$ and
$\mu (n)$ is the Möbius function?
Heuristic: Up to x there must be roughly the same portion of numbers with odd and even number of prime divisors. First equality ( equivalent to prime number theorem ) prooves that for square free numbers, and there is no reason why should it not be valid for all numbers

Comment: What makes you believe one can make such a deduction?

Comment: Heuristic: Up to x there must be roughly the same portion of numbers with odd and even number of prime divisors. First equality ( equivalent to prime number theorem ) prooves that for square free numbers, and there is no reason why should it not be valid for all numbers .

Comment: @AndrejLeško It might be good to include that heuristic in the question itself.

Comment: O.k. "heuristic" is included in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that deduction is possible, but somewhat indirectly.

The estimate $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = o(x)$ is equivalent to the nonvanishing of $\zeta(s)$ on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ since both conditions are known to be equivalent to the prime number theorem. (Maybe one can directly deduce the estimate and the nonvanishing from each other without going *through* the prime number theorem, but that's a side issue here.) The function $\zeta(s)$ is known by elementary techniques to be meromorphic on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ with a simple pole at $s = 1$, so the nonvanishing of $\zeta(s)$ on that line is equivalent to the function $1/\zeta(s)$ being analytic on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$.  I will show $\sum_{n \leq x} (-1)^{\omega(n)} = o(x)$ follows from analyticity of $1/\zeta(s)$ on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$, so in a rather indirect way $\sum_{n \leq x} (-1)^{\omega(n)} = o(x)$ follows from the estimate $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = o(x)$.

Set $F(s) := \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^{\omega(n)}/n^s$ for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$.
As David Speyer observed in his answer, for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$ we have
$$
F(s) = 
\prod_p \frac{1-2/p^s}{1-1/p^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\prod_p \frac{1-2/p^s}{(1-1/p^s)^2} 
$$
and the $p$-th term on the right for ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$ is $1 + O(1/p^{2s})$ with $O$-constant $4$ since $|1/p^{s}| \leq 1/2^{{\rm Re}(s)} \leq 1/2$ and
$(1-2z)/(1-z)^2 = 1 + O(z^2)$ for $|z| \leq 1/2$ with $O$-constant $4$: $(1-2z)/(1-z)^2 - 1 = -z^2/(1-z)^2$ and $|1/(1-z)^2| \leq 4$.  So the infinite product over $p$ on the right, which David calls $B(s)$, is holomorphic for ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$ (in fact, $B(s)$ converges and is holomorphic for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2$ since $\sum 1/p^{2s}$ converges for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2$). Since $\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic on ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$, $F(s)$ has a meromorphic continuation to ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$.

From $1/\zeta(s)$ being analytic on ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$, $F(s)$ has an analytic continuation to ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$. Now we will apply the following theorem, which is a consequence of Newman's Tauberian theorem (one of the approaches to  proving the prime number theorem).

**Theorem**.  *If the Dirichlet series* $\sum_{n \geq 1} b_n/n^s$ *converges for* ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$, $|b_n| \leq 1$, *and the series has an analytic continuation to* ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$ *then* $(1/x)\sum_{n \leq x} b_n \to 0$ *as* $x \to \infty$.

In this theorem use $b_n = (-1)^{\omega(n)}$ to see that analyticity of $1/\zeta(s)$ on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ implies $(1/x)\sum_{n \leq x}(-1)^{\omega(n)} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

What about a converse: does $(1/x)\sum_{n \leq x}(-1)^{\omega(n)} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ imply $1/\zeta(s)$ is analytic on ${\rm Re}(s) =1$ (and thus imply $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = o(x)$)?  Set $A(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} (-1)^{\omega(n)}$, so trivially $|A(x)/x|$ is bounded and we are assuming that in fact $A(x)/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

We already pointed out that the Dirichlet series $F(s) = \sum (-1)^{\omega(n)}/n^s$ has a meromorphic continuation to ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$ without using any information about possible zeros of $\zeta(s)$ on the line ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$.

**Theorem**.  *Assume a Dirichlet series* $G(s) := \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n/n^s$ *converges for* ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$ *and* $G(s)$ *has a meromorphic continuation to* ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$. *If* $(1/x)\sum_{n \leq x} a_n \to 0$ *as* $x \to \infty$ *then* $G(s)$ *is holomorphic on the line* ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$.

Use this theorem with $a_n = (-1)^{\omega(n)}$ to see that if $A(x)/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, then $F(s)$ is holomorphic on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$. What does analyticity of $F(s)$ on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ tell us about analyticity of $1/\zeta(s)$ on that line?  In the formula for $F(s)$ as an infinite product over primes when ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$, let's extract the $p = 2$ term:
$$
F(s) = 
\prod_p \frac{1-2/p^s}{1-1/p^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\frac{1-2/2^s}{(1-1/2^s)^2}\prod_{p \geq 3} \frac{1-2/p^s}{(1-1/p^s)^2}. 
$$
To reciprocate the product on the right over $p \geq 3$, let's see how quickly the reciprocals of the factors tend to $1$.
For $|z| \leq 1/3$ we have $(1-z)^2/(1-2z) = 1 + z^2/(1-2z)$ and $|1/(1-2z)| \leq 3$, so
$(1-z)^2/(1-2z) = 1 + O(z^2)$ with $O$-constant $3$.
Therefore $(1-1/p^s)^2/(1-2/p^s) = 1 + O(1/p^{2s})$ for ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$ and $p \geq 3$ with $O$-constant 3, so
$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\frac{1-2/2^s}{(1-1/2^s)^2} = F(s)\cdot\prod_{p \geq 3} \frac{(1-1/p^s)^2}{1-2/p^s}
$$
where the product on the right converges and is analytic for ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$ (and in fact for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2$). Therefore analyticity of $F(s)$ on the line ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ implies the expression on the left side of the displayed equation just above is analytic on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$. The factor $1-1/2^s$ is nonvanishing on ${\rm Re}(s) > 0$, so
$(1-2/2^s)/\zeta(s)$ is analytic on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$. Since $1-2/2^s$ is analytic on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ with zeros only at the points $s_k = 1 + 2\pi ik/\log 2$ where $k \in \mathbf Z$, the meromorphic function $1/\zeta(s)$ is analytic on
the line ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ except for possible poles at the points $s_k$.

All that remains to be done to get the desired converse result is show $1/\zeta(s)$ has no pole at each $s_k$, or equivalently that $\zeta(s)$ is nonvanishing at each $s_k$. I don't see right now how to do that in the context of this problem. (While we *know* $\zeta(s) \not= 0$ on the whole line ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ from methods used to prove the prime number theorem, it's not fair to use such arguments here.) I am reminded here of the trick of comparing the products $(1-2/2^s)\zeta(s)$ and $(1-3/3^s)\zeta(s)$ in one of the proofs that $\zeta(s)$ is analytic on ${\rm Re}(s) > 0$ except for a simple pole at $s = 1$, but I don't see how to modify that.
If someone has a useful suggestion to finish this argument, please put it in the comments.

Comment: All is clear. I have one question: can we from 1. $\sum_{n\leqslant x}(-1)^{\omega(n)}=o(x)$ deduce the Prime number theorem or 1. is weaker than PNT?

Comment: @AndrejLeško I added a second part to my solution that almost (but not quite) answers the question in your comment affirmatively, but at the very end I got stuck.

Answer (score 8):

Let $f(n)$ be the multiplicative function with $f(p^k) = 1-k$. Then
$$(-1)^{\omega(n)} = \sum_{d|n} f(d) \mu(n/d).$$
(Proof: Both sides are multiplicative, so we just need to check prime powers, which is easy.)

Then
$$\sum_{n \leq x} (-1)^{\omega(n)} = \sum_{d \leq x} f(d) \sum_{m \leq x/d} \mu(m).$$
If the absolute value of the inner sum is bounded by $C (x/d)$, then we have bounded the LHS by
$$\sum_{d\leq x} |f(d)| \cdot C (x/d).$$
We win if we can show that $\sum_{d=1}^{\infty} |f(d)|/d$ is convergent.

To see that this is plausible, note that $f(d)=0$ if there is any prime factor of $d$ whose square does not divide $d$. To actually prove this, since it is a sum of positive terms, we may rearrange to an Euler product, and our goal is to show that
$$\prod_p (1+1/p^2 + 2/p^3 + 3/p^4+ \cdots) = \prod_p \left( 1+\tfrac{1}{p^2 (1-1/p)^2} \right)= \prod_p \left( 1+\tfrac{1}{(p-1)^2} \right)$$
is convergent.

The last is clear.

---

Morally, why this should work:

$$\sum_n \frac{(-1)^{\omega(n)}}{n^s} = \prod_p \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^s} - \frac{1}{p^{2s}} - \cdots \right) = \prod_p \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^s} \right) \left( 1-O(1/p^{-2s}) \right)$$
$$=: \left( \sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \right) B(s)$$
where $B(s)$ is defined as the product of the error terms.

The product defining $B(s)$ converges to the right of $Re(s)=1/2$, so $\sum_n \tfrac{(-1)^{\omega(n)}}{n^s}$ and $\sum_n \tfrac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ have the same zeroes and poles on the line $Re(s)=1$.  So partial sums of $(-1)^{\omega(n)}$ and $\mu(n)$ should have similar behavior.

Actually, there is a slight error here: The $p=2$ term is $(1-1/2^{2s} -2/2^{3s}-3/2^{4s}-\cdots)$ which approaches $1-1/4-2/8-3/16-\cdots = 0$ as $s \to 1$. So $B(s)$ has an extra zero at $s=1$, with the result that $\sum_n \tfrac{(-1)^{\omega(n)}}{n^s}$ vanishes with order $2$ as $s \to 1$ and $\sum_n \tfrac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ only vanishes to order $1$. Fortunately, when I tried to make the argument elementary, it worked out anyway. But this looks like it will pose a problem for reversing the argument in such an easy way.

The function $f(n)$ was motivated by $B(s) = \sum_n f(n)/n^s$. The remaining step was then to remove the complex analysis and see if a simple bound would go directly from one partial sum to the other.

Comment: Is this rigorous proof? What does it mean that " partial sums of $(-1)^{\omega(n)}$ and $\mu(n)$ should have similar behavior" ?

Comment: @AndrejLeško The first half of the post is a rigorous proof, the second is an intuitive derivation of the argument.

Comment: Could I recommend changing the name $\phi(n)$ to something more generic, like $f(n)$? It took me a minute to realize it doesn't denote the totient function.

Comment: Okay, $\phi$ changed to $f$.

Comment: Ok, now i understand the proof,the second part is motivation, it is clear,  but is it possible to proove the deduction in oposite direction in other words: are the two equalities in my question equivalent to each other? This would mean tha PNT is equivalent to $\sum_{n\leqslant x}(-1)^{\omega(n)}=o(x)$

Comment: This seems less easy. Copying the approach above, you would now want a multiplicative function $g$ such that $\mu(n) = \sum_{d|n} g(d) (-1)^{\omega(n/d)}$. I compute that $g(p^k) = 2^{k-1}$ for $k \geq 1$ (and $g(1) = 1$). But then $\sum_k g(2^k)/2^k$ is divergent, so we need to be a little careful ...

Comment: Does it mean that $\sum_{n\leqslant x}(-1)^{\omega(n)}=o(x)$ is weaker than $\sum_{n\leqslant x}\mu (n)=o(x) $, which would be strange because in first case we have statement about all numbers ( up to x ) and in second about square free numbers ( a portion of all numbers )?

Comment: @AndrejLeško while squarefree numbers are only a portion of all numbers, they "know" about all numbers.  For example, $\sum \mu(n)/n^s = 1/\zeta(s)$  for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$ is a series supported on the squarefree numbers but its reciprocal $\zeta(s) = \sum 1/n^s$ is a series supported on all positive integers.

Comment: It is plausible, so if square free numbers (SFN) "know"about all numbers, is it possible to develop the whole number theory based only on SFN?

Comment: @AndrejLeško Perhaps it's also worth noting the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ can be evaluated as $\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\omega(n)\,M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ where $M(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\mu(n)$ and $\omega(n)$ is the number of unique primes dividing $n$.

Comment: I thinck, It is not quite the same: for evaluating M(x) we realy need only squre free numbers, but than we need to know the values of $\omega(n)$ for all numbers to evaluate $\pi(x)$